# Listindex to set activecell

Tags: excel

In a user form I have a combobox that is populated from column 1 of a spreadsheet.  I am trying to set the cell active that contains the value of what is selected in the combo box.

Private Sub CmbBox_Change()

(CmbBox.ListIndex + 1).select

Once the active cell is defined I want to populate labels on a form with other contents of other cells in the row.
label1.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)

How to the get the cell in column A active when its value is selected from the combo box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the listbox is populated in the same order it appears on the sheet you can simply use the **ListIndex** property as if it was your offset value. For example:

```
Range("A1").Offset(CmbBox.ListIndex, 0).Select
```

Alternatively if your listbox is sorted differently you would need to use the **Find** method instead of using an offset.